Formed equilateral triangles
I have met recently a strange question about triangle which asking about the triangle in harmonic analysis.
How many equilateral triangles are formed in a regular polygon whose vertices are the vertices of the polygon?

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!

I suggest you try counting the number of equilateral triangles in the following picture and try to discover a pattern:


Image from:  https://mathmonks.com/polygon/regular-and-irregular-polygons
